# Why 2-step Flyway update advised when updating from Spring Boot 1.5.x to 2.1.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I am currently updating a Spring Boot 1.5.19 application to Spring Boot 2.1.8. The application uses Flyway for automatic schema migration. I stumbled accross a [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot2.0-Migration-Guide#flyway) which advises to first upgrade to FlyWay 4, and after that update to Flyway 5.
I updated directly from Spring Boot 1.5.19 to 2.1.8 and Flyway is working fine. Am I missing something here? Why am I supposed to upgrade to Flyway 4 first?

I noticed checksums are calculated different with the new version, but my application seems to work fine with the old checksum vales in the schema_version table in my database.

Any insights would be much appreciated!